# FOOTER div wont to be at bottom and get over another divs

Tags: html, css

I have built a template however the footer div won't position cleanly beneath all other divs.

The source code can be found here:
http://businesstrends.co.il/learn/question.php

Here is source code incase the page goes down:

```
<div id="content">
    Content
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
    Sidebar
</div><br>

<div id="footer">
    Footer
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#head {
    width: 1200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 75px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#content {
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 890px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
}

#sidebar {
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Please add relevant code in the question...without that the question could be useless for future users if your page goes down.

Comment: Just add `clear:both` on the footer after that remove this question please :)

Comment: @Danko **BAM!** and the dirt is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve it your page structure needs to look like that

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
     <div class="content">

     <!-- all your page content goes here with header -->


           <div class="stop"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="footer">
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    html{height:100%}
    body{height:100%;margin:0}
    .content{height:auto !important;min-height:100%}

   .stop{height:40px;clear:both}
   .footer{width:100%;height:40px;background-color:red;margin-top:-40px}
```

.stop elements will prevent footer from overlapping your content, also needs to be set to height of your footer.

.footer needs to have minus margin equals its height.

Footer will always stay on the bottom of the page

http://jsfiddle.net/Du94N/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this for start :P

```
#footer {
background-color: #fff;
width: 1200px;
height: 75px;
border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
margin-top: 15px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :)

```
#footer {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try floating the footer to the left, that should put it under all the divs

```
#footer {
    float:left;
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Help me Thanks.! but theres another way to get the reqoult?

Comment: @user3232398, there are probably a few more ways to get the result. Have a look at the other answers on this page - such as Esser's answer about adding clear:both; to the footer. Try that :)

Comment: i tried it is not working

Comment: @user3232398, OK - did my solution work at all? If not try Gabriel Lindgren's answer see if that works at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking but is this to any help?

```
#footer {
    background-color:#fff;
    width:1200px;
    height:75px;
    border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}


<div id="footer">
Text here
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add `clear:both:`. By the way, your title, links and meta belong in the head, not in the body.